# How do I choose a random value from an array with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: Getting random value from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/javascript-getting-random-value-from-an-array)

I have an external js with the following line:

```
var postmessage = "hi my favorite site is http://google.com";
```

but is there a way to pick a site a random from an array so like this

```
var postmessage = "hi my favorite site is +'random'";

random= http://google.com, http://yahoo.com, http://msn.com, http://apple.com
```

how do i make it work?

Comment: Getting the language right in the title would be a start

Comment: first: your title of your post should be "Javascript" .... shouldnt it? you can init an array with: var random = array(....); and then take an index with "Math.random()"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45606635/8202629

Answer (score 29):

```
var favorites = ["http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com", "http://msn.com", "http://apple.com"];
var favorite = favorites[Math.floor(Math.random() * favorites.length)];
var postmessage = "hi my favorite site is " + favorite;
```

Create an array of your sites, then pick one element from the array. You do this by choosing a random number using [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random), which gives you a result greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1. Multiply by the length of your array, and take the [floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) (that is, take just the integer part, dropping off any decimal points), so you will have a number from 0 to one less than the length of your array (which will thus be a valid index into your array). Use that result to pick an element from your array.

Comment: Has a bug -- needs a paren after `favorites.length`.

Comment: `Math.round(7.919417901018048);// 8` & `Math.floor(7.919417901018048); // 7`

Answer (score 4):

```
var sites = new Array('http://www.google.com', "http://www.stackoverflow.com")

var postmessage = "hi my favorite site is" + sites[Math.round(Math.random()*(sites.length-1))];
```

First stick all of your sites in an array. Then get a random number from the array length (the -1 is because an array is zero indexed and the length that is returned starts at 1)

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
function getRandomSite(){
   var sites = ["google.com","bing.com","xyz.com","abc.com","example.com"];
    var i = parseInt(Math.random()*(sites.length-1));
    return sites[i];
};
```

Comment: Since you're multiplying by 10, and then testing whether it is larger than the length, you're introducing a bias for the last site in the list: it will be picked much more often (almost 50% of the time, in your example). Rather multiply with the length of the array.

Comment: Hi, I thought about this right after I answered the question. You're totally right here.