# ECMAScript 2015 Features (Math + Number + String + Object APIs)?

Tags: arrays, object, iterator, ecmascript-6, babeljs

**How to can I get the value of each array object iterator?**
*I just have some confused, anybody can help ?*

```js
let x, y, z;

x = ["a", "b", "c"].entries();
console.log("x = " + x);
// iterator [0, "a"], [1,"b"], [2,"c"]

y = ["a", "b", "c"].keys();
console.log("y = " + y);
// iterator 0, 1, 2

z = ["a", "b", "c"].values();
console.log("z = " + z);
// iterator "a", "b", "c"

// x = [object Array Iterator]
// y = [object Array Iterator]
// z = [object Array Iterator]

/*
how to can I get the value of each array object iterator?
*/
```

[http://babeljs.io/repl/?](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact&code=var%20x%20%3B%0D%0Ax%20%3D%20%5B%22a%22%2C%20%22b%22%2C%20%22c%22%5D.entries()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%22x%20%3D%20%22%20%2B%20x)%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20iterator%20%5B0%2C%20%22a%22%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C%22b%22%5D%2C%20%5B2%2C%22c%22%5D%0D%0Ax%20%3D%20%5B%22a%22%2C%20%22b%22%2C%20%22c%22%5D.keys()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%22x%20%3D%20%22%20%2B%20x)%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20iterator%200%2C%201%2C%202%0D%0Ax%20%3D%20%5B%22a%22%2C%20%22b%22%2C%20%22c%22%5D.values()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%22x%20%3D%20%22%20%2B%20x)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A)
[image]

Comment: If you just want to get the values out of an iterator, MDN has a good summary: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"value of each array object iterator"*. Do you want to consume the iterators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert an iterator object to an array:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']

console.log(Array.from(arr.keys()))
```

See also [Iteration protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

## Here is my solution!

> you can follow my steps if you get a obstruct!

https://github.com/gildata/RAIO/issues/61

## steps

1. objects to array, `{{},{}} => arr = [{},{}];`

> for in & key

2. get object's title , `title = key;`

> for in & key

3. create a new object `obj = {title, arr};`

> Object.assign(obj, {new_key: "new value"});

4. wrapped array , `array.push(obj);`

> for of / for in

5. just use the wrapped array

> array.map() & Table

```js
    // fetch data by `ReportName` & `GetRowSchema`
    outputClick = () => {
        fetch(`https://cdn.xgqfrms.xyz/json/tables.json`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json)=> {
            console.log(`json = ${json}`);
            console.log(`json.length = ${json.length}`);
            console.log(`json.Info`, json.Info.schema.Properties);
            // Properties
            let datas = [];
            if(json.Info.schema.Properties !== undefined){
                // datas.BasicInformationRow.Properties
                datas = json.Info.schema.Properties;
            }else{
                let tables = json.Info.schema;
                // let i = 0;
                for (let key in tables) {
                    let arr = [];
                    let new_obj = {};
                    let i = 0;
                    if(!tables.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
                    if (tables.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        let title = tables[key].desc,
                            objs = tables[key].Properties;
                        for (let key in objs) {
                            if (objs.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                // A0
                                objs[key].name =  key;
                                objs[key].key = ("k000" + i++);
                            }
                            arr.push(objs[key]);
                            console.log(`arr ${key}`, arr);
                        }
                        console.log(`title ${key}`, title);
                        new_obj.title = tables[key].desc;
                        new_obj.datas = arr;
                        console.log(`new obj = `, new_obj);
                    }
                    datas.push(new_obj);
                    const css = `
                        color: #0f0;
                        font-size: 23px;
                    `;
                    const css2 = `
                        color: #f00;
                        font-size: 16px;
                    `;
                    console.log(`%c datas key = ${key} \n datas = `, css, datas);
                    console.log(`%c datas i = ${i} \n datas = `, css2, datas[i]);
                    // i++;
                }
            }
            console.log(`datas[0] = `, datas[0]);
            console.log(`datas[0].length = `, datas[0].length);
            // Array.isArrray(datas[0]);
            console.log(`Array.isArray(datas[0]) = `, Array.isArray(datas[0]));
            console.log(`typeof datas[0] = `, typeof(datas[0]));
            this.setState(
                {
                    output_datas: datas
                }
            );
            return datas;
        });
    };
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708784/how-do-i-choose-a-random-value-from-an-array-with-javascript